# How to make global variable and how to use in roku?

Tags: variables, global-variables, roku, brightscript

m.menuRowList = m.top.findNode("MenuRowList")

how to make  "m.menuRowList" global variable

how can i use the m.menuRowList variable in the whole project

Thank you for advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in the global node.

```html
menuRowList = m.top.FinNode("menuRowList")
globalNode = GetGlobalAA().global
globalNode.Update({
  menuRowList: menuRowList
}, true)
```

After this, it can be accessed anywhere inside the current roScreen.